# VNC black screen

Tags: vnc

I start vnc client on remote computer with command "x11vnc -display :2". Then I try to connect to it from my local computer with command "xvnc4viewer" then it asks for server name and eventually shows me black screen.

Output of x11vnc:

```
###############################################################
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
#@                                                           @#
#@  **  WARNING  **  WARNING  **  WARNING  **  WARNING  **   @#
#@                                                           @#
#@        YOU ARE RUNNING X11VNC WITHOUT A PASSWORD!!        @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  This means anyone with network access to this computer   @#
#@  may be able to view and control your desktop.            @#
#@                                                           @#
#@ >>> If you did not mean to do this Press CTRL-C now!! <<< @#
#@                                                           @#
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
#@                                                           @#
#@  You can create an x11vnc password file by running:       @#
#@                                                           @#
#@       x11vnc -storepasswd password /path/to/passfile      @#
#@  or   x11vnc -storepasswd /path/to/passfile               @#
#@  or   x11vnc -storepasswd                                 @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  (the last one will use ~/.vnc/passwd)                    @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  and then starting x11vnc via:                            @#
#@                                                           @#
#@      x11vnc -rfbauth /path/to/passfile                    @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  an existing ~/.vnc/passwd file from another VNC          @#
#@  application will work fine too.                          @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  You can also use the -passwdfile or -passwd options.     @#
#@  (note -passwd is unsafe if local users are not trusted)  @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Make sure any -rfbauth and -passwdfile password files    @#
#@  cannot be read by untrusted users.                       @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Use x11vnc -usepw to automatically use your              @#
#@  ~/.vnc/passwd or ~/.vnc/passwdfile password files.       @#
#@  (and prompt you to create ~/.vnc/passwd if neither       @#
#@  file exists.)  Under -usepw, x11vnc will exit if it      @#
#@  cannot find a password to use.                           @#
#@                                                           @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Even with a password, the subsequent VNC traffic is      @#
#@  sent in the clear.  Consider tunnelling via ssh(1):      @#
#@                                                           @#
#@    http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/#tunnelling            @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Or using the x11vnc SSL options: -ssl and -stunnel       @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Please Read the documention for more info about          @#
#@  passwords, security, and encryption.                     @#
#@                                                           @#
#@    http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-passwd    @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  To disable this warning use the -nopw option, or put     @#
#@  'nopw' on a line in your ~/.x11vncrc file.               @#
#@                                                           @#
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
###############################################################
14/10/2015 13:41:22 x11vnc version: 0.9.14 lastmod: 2010-12-27  pid: 9083
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Using X display :2
14/10/2015 13:41:22 rootwin: 0x4f reswin: 0x400001 dpy: 0x29bd4d0
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 ------------------ USEFUL INFORMATION ------------------
14/10/2015 13:41:22 X DAMAGE available on display, using it for polling hints.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   To disable this behavior use: '-noxdamage'
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22   Most compositing window managers like 'compiz' or 'beryl'
14/10/2015 13:41:22   cause X DAMAGE to fail, and so you may not see any screen
14/10/2015 13:41:22   updates via VNC.  Either disable 'compiz' (recommended) or
14/10/2015 13:41:22   supply the x11vnc '-noxdamage' command line option.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 X COMPOSITE available on display, using it for window polling.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   To disable this behavior use: '-noxcomposite'
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Wireframing: -wireframe mode is in effect for window moves.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
14/10/2015 13:41:22   errors, etc) it may be disabled:
14/10/2015 13:41:22    - use '-nowf' to disable wireframing completely.
14/10/2015 13:41:22    - use '-nowcr' to disable the Copy Rectangle after the
14/10/2015 13:41:22      moved window is released in the new position.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
14/10/2015 13:41:22   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
14/10/2015 13:41:22   periodic repaints.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 XFIXES available on display, resetting cursor mode
14/10/2015 13:41:22   to: '-cursor most'.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   to disable this behavior use: '-cursor arrow'
14/10/2015 13:41:22   or '-noxfixes'.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 using XFIXES for cursor drawing.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 GrabServer control via XTEST.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Scroll Detection: -scrollcopyrect mode is in effect to
14/10/2015 13:41:22   use RECORD extension to try to detect scrolling windows
14/10/2015 13:41:22   (induced by either user keystroke or mouse input).
14/10/2015 13:41:22   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
14/10/2015 13:41:22   errors, etc) it may be disabled via: '-noscr'
14/10/2015 13:41:22   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
14/10/2015 13:41:22   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
14/10/2015 13:41:22   periodic repaints.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 XKEYBOARD: number of keysyms per keycode 7 is greater
14/10/2015 13:41:22   than 4 and 51 keysyms are mapped above 4.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   Automatically switching to -xkb mode.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   If this makes the key mapping worse you can
14/10/2015 13:41:22   disable it with the "-noxkb" option.
14/10/2015 13:41:22   Also, remember "-remap DEAD" for accenting characters.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 X FBPM extension not supported.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 X DPMS extension not supported.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 --------------------------------------------------------
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Default visual ID: 0x21
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Read initial data from X display into framebuffer.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/4096
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 X display :2 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Autoprobing TCP port 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5900
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Autoprobing TCP6 port 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5900
14/10/2015 13:41:22 listen6: bind: Address already in use
14/10/2015 13:41:22 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 fb read rate: 1900 MB/sec
14/10/2015 13:41:22 fast read: reset -wait  ms to: 10
14/10/2015 13:41:22 fast read: reset -defer ms to: 10
14/10/2015 13:41:22 The X server says there are 10 mouse buttons.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 screen setup finished.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 
14/10/2015 13:41:22 WARNING: You are running x11vnc WITHOUT a password.  See
14/10/2015 13:41:22 WARNING: the warning message printed above for more info.
14/10/2015 13:41:22 

The VNC desktop is:      u-pl14:0

******************************************************************************
Have you tried the x11vnc '-ncache' VNC client-side pixel caching feature yet?

The scheme stores pixel data offscreen on the VNC viewer side for faster
retrieval.  It should work with any VNC viewer.  Try it by running:

    x11vnc -ncache 10 ...

One can also add -ncache_cr for smooth 'copyrect' window motion.
More info: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-client-caching

14/10/2015 13:42:00 Got connection from client 195.113.16.31
14/10/2015 13:42:00   other clients:
14/10/2015 13:42:00 Normal socket connection
14/10/2015 13:42:00 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
14/10/2015 13:42:00   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
14/10/2015 13:42:00 incr accepted_client=1 for 195.113.16.31:45948  sock=11
14/10/2015 13:42:00 Client Protocol Version 3.8
14/10/2015 13:42:00 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
14/10/2015 13:42:00 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 1
14/10/2015 13:42:00 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: returning securityResult for client rfb version >= 3.8
14/10/2015 13:42:00 Pixel format for client 195.113.16.31:
14/10/2015 13:42:00   8 bpp, depth 6
14/10/2015 13:42:00   true colour: max r 3 g 3 b 3, shift r 4 g 2 b 0
14/10/2015 13:42:00 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 195.113.16.31
14/10/2015 13:42:00 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 195.113.16.31
14/10/2015 13:42:00 Using ZRLE encoding for client 195.113.16.31
14/10/2015 13:42:01 client_set_net: 195.113.16.31  0.0004
14/10/2015 13:42:01 created   xdamage object: 0x400024
14/10/2015 13:42:08 client_count: 0
14/10/2015 13:42:08 Restored X server key autorepeat to: 1
14/10/2015 13:42:08 viewer exited.
14/10/2015 13:42:08 deleted 32 tile_row polling images.
```

Output of xvnc11viewer:

```
VNC Viewer Free Edition 4.1.1 for X - built Apr  2 2015 21:51:06
   Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
   See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
   Server: 
   Wed Oct 14 13:42:00 2015
    CConn:       connected to host u-pl14.ms.mff.cuni.cz port 5900
    CConnection: Server supports RFB protocol version 3.8
    CConnection: Using RFB protocol version 3.8
    TXImage:     Using default colormap and visual, TrueColor, depth 24.
    CConn:       Using pixel format depth 6 (8bpp) rgb222
    CConn:       Using ZRLE encoding
```

Can anyone help me with it? Thanks